# How can I convince SSH hosts to forget my old keys?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm setting up an Ubuntu 14.04 laptop for work, for the second time (very long story, don't ask). I had previously logged into a bunch of our servers at work using an RSA key stored in my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files on those hosts. Then I had to blow away my original installation and started over. So the second time around I generated a new SSH key, with the same hostname. Then I went back to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files on the servers and replaced the old key with the new one. Now they all refuse to authenticate me from the new installation.

`Host key verification failed.`

I've already tried:

- a couple of rounds of re-creating my laptop's RSA key
- `ssh-keygen -R $LAPTOP_NAME` on each server

  - This is interesting only in that if I diff the resultant `known_hosts` and `known_hosts.old` files, they're identical, as if the host wasn't actually listed.
- `sudo ssh-keygen -f $ROOT_KNOWN_HOSTS_LOCATION -R $LAPTOP_NAME`, since I have `sudo` access on the remote hosts.

None of these individually or in combination had any effect.

At this point I'm at a loss as to how to convince the remote servers to authenticate me with the new keys.

Comment: Have you tried `ssh-copy-id user@hostname` to each server?

Comment: @Terrance Nope, I had parallel access to the servers via a VM which had already been authenticated successfully, so I was copying the key values back and forth via that VM.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is going to be entirely unsatisfactory as an answer, but I've now solved the issue, and the solution was… to wait. I'm not sure what difference it made, but I went off and did other things and then came back to try again, and it magically worked. I… don't get it. I would rather say I withdraw my question, than to have this be the answer.

Sigh.